# Class in python not taking argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

As you can see in this python code, I am trying to learn about class in python. But this code is showing an error.

> arpi = stu("arpit", 26)
> TypeError: stu() takes no arguments

```
class stu:
    def __int__(self, name,age):
        self.name= name
        self.age=age

arpi = stu("arpit", 26)
print(arpi.name)
```

Comment: There is a typo: The method must be named `__init__` not `__int__`.

Answer (score 2):

your function in the class is wrong.  It's meant to be `__init__(...)` not `__int__(...)`

```
>>> class stu:
...    def __init__(self, name, age):
...       self.name=name
...       self.age=age
...
>>> arpi=stu("arpit", 26)
>>> arpi.name
'arpit'
>>> arpi.age
26
>>>
```